# Is it Possible to get a empty JSON structure from a Mongoose Schema

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider I am having a Mongoose Schema defined:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
field: mongoose.Schema.Types.String
});
```

now can I get the empty JSON object, something like

```
var MyJSON = MySchema.getJSON();  //This is where I want answers
```

So that MyJSON will be:

```
{
field:'';
}
```

So I can create a Empty JSON object and use it, like:

```
MyJSON.field = 'my_new_value';
```

Advanced Thanks for help..

Comment: What does it mean when you declare `field: Schema.Type`?  I've never seen that.  I can't really understand what you're asking either, can you clarify your question?

Comment: Its nothing but mongoose.Schema.Types. Firstly to clarify my question. I need to get a JSON obj out of my Mongoose Schema Obj.

Comment: You *can* do `MyJSON.field = 'my_new_value';` on any object already. You do not need to get an empty object for that. But maybe you mean that you want to iterate over the fields in the object? In that case, there's some tricky cases to consider, such as what happens when your schema includes arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the Schema using a static

```
MySchema.statics.getJSON = function(done) {
  var result = Object.keys(this.schema.paths);
  done(null, result);
};
```

You can then just call it like this

```
Events.getJSON( function(err, result) {
  // deal with your JSON data here;
});
```